Scraping Yahoo historical crypto prices stopped working
I used to scrape Yahoo for historical crypto data in Google Sheets. This stopped working. It looks like the website of Yahoo also has changed a bit.
I used to use for example:

=INDEX(IMPORTREGEX("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/BTC-USD/history?period1=1725062400&period2=1725062400","<td.?>(.?)</td>"),5)

Now this returns #REF!
I already tried some other IMPORTREGEX options, but I can't seem to retrieve anything with this function.
Would it still be possible to scrape the information within Google Sheets?

This function will help you to get the live current BTC-USD value on finance.yahoo.com.
You can use the function in a cell as =getBTC()
.

.
  function getBTC() {
    var url='https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/BTC-USD'

    try {
      var httpResponse = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{'muteHttpExceptions': true});
        } catch (e) {
          return e.toString();
      }
      
    var responseContent = httpResponse.getContentText();
    var responseCode = httpResponse.getResponseCode();
      
    if (responseCode == 200) {      
      objJSON = JSON.parse(responseContent);

      return objJSON.chart.result[0].meta.regularMarketPrice;
    }
    else if (responseCode !== 200){
      
      return 'Error with response code:' + responseCode;
    }
}

